# Nested loops in Programming

Tags: c

How will I show the number of iterations inside the inner while loop using the code below. I wanted to iterate the inner loop from the number of iterations from the outer loop.

```
printf("value: ");
scanf("%d", &x[0]);

/*printf("%d", x[0]);*/

 loop: while(a < x[0])
{
        while(b < x[0]) {
        b++;
}
printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
a++;
goto loop;
}
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the increment inside the outer loop

Comment: I've tried that one but it does not work

Comment: Why `goto loop`? What you do is equivalent of `continue` at the end of the loop, when it would *naturally* continue iteration anyway.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please edit your question to show the *actual* output (without destroying e.g. my edits, please).

Comment: And please mind the formatting changed made by others edits, it's often there to make things easier to read.

Comment: You haven't shown how `a` or `b` (or `numbers`) are defined , nor how `a` and `b` are initialized. Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses; MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: You just need to move the `printf` statement that prinrts the values of `a` and `b` into the body of the inner loop to get the output you're expecting.  Having said that, why are you using a `goto`?  It's not necessary, and makes your code confusing to read.

Answer (score 2):

Why you use `while` loops? Always use `for` loops when you know the number of iteration. You know the number of iterations, because you set it as an input.
So you can rewrite your code to this (based on the rare information you give and without input check):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int Input;

    printf("Enter a value: ");
    scanf("%d", &Input);

    for(int i = 0; i < Input; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= Input; j++)
        {
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or with `while` loops (bad style)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int Input;

    printf("Enter a value: ");
    scanf("%d", &Input);

    while(i < Input)
    {
        j = 0;

        while(j <= Input)
        {
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Both ways gives you the following output:

```
Enter a value: 2
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot use while loop to achieve this result of the for loop?

Comment: You can use `while` loops, but you have to define the end of the `while` loop in the correct code line. But why you want to use a `while` loop if you need a loop with a known number of iterations? You use `while` loops only when you wait for an unknown amount of time (waiting for an external signal as an example).

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know why you code like this, the working code is following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int x = 2;
    int a = 0, b = 0;

loop:while( a < x )
    {
        while(b <= x) {
            printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            b++;
        }

        ++a;
        b = 0;
        goto loop;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the 2 above answers give you a working code, I'd like to list what's wrong in what you do:

- 1) Your printf isn't in the inner loop, so B will increment to 2 before reaching the printf. 2) you forget to reset b between each main loop. 3) You want (b <= numbers[0]) and not (b < numbers[0])  --> that is why your output isn't the one you expected.

if you want to keep your code with the style errors, you could just move the printf two lines up, reset b and change your operator =>

```
printf("Enter a value: ");
scanf("%d", &numbers[0]);

/*printf("%d", numbers[0]);*/

loop: while(a < numbers[0])
{
    b = 0;
    while(b <= numbers[0]) {
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
        b++;
    }
    a++;
    goto loop;
}
```

- You are using goto in quite a weird way. The control will go back to the while loop at the end of it, you don't need to jump there by hand. As a guideline, you could just take into account that the use of goto is very rarely the best way to write a code in C.
- You use while loops where you could have used for ones. While are more used in loops with an input based condition =>

```
while (input_string != "END") 
{
    input_string = user_interaction ();
    // some code
}
```

while (input_string != "END") {} for instance.